# ReactJs how to dynamically render a page based on user selection?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic

I'm trying to build an E-commerce shop and using the rule "Don't repeat yourself", I have a data.Js file that contains an array of objects - each object is a corresponding watch (has name, ID, price, description and other details). I have all the watches displayed on the homepage, like this:

[image]

What i want is:

When a user clicks on a specific watch, to then be taken to the product page that corresponds to the specific watch (I.E. get populated with data matching the correct object, with {item.id} and {item.title} and {item.price} and etc.

How can I do this so that React knows which watch the user clicks and how to populate the product page with the correct data?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet of this?

Comment: Read about react router https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Map through the array of object using a list tag making each list unique with the id property of each object. You can embed the list within a react-router Link which can be used to navigate to the page to display the details.

```js
//Assume your array of object is watchData 
return (
    <ul>
      {watchData?.map((data) => (
        <Link to"watch-details">  
          <li key={data.id}>
            {watchData.image}
          </li>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
```